# Are there any good alternatives to "a fire inside" of someone?

Tags: characters, character-development, description, emotions

I'm trying to express the idea of a character undergoing a realisation, thus feeling an idea along the lines of a "fire being ignited inside of him".

However, I was wondering, are there any better ways to express this? (I feel like the fire metaphor is slightly overused)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here.  Were a character realizing something, I would normally say -- if I were being metaphorical -- something to effect of "it dawned on him."  This might, in turn, light a fire inside him, but that would mean it inspired him to act.

Comment: Is there a reason why "He realized..." isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1):

### This depends on what the realisation causes him to do.

**1. If the realisation causes him to do something,** you could describe the metaphor as:

> "The realisation pushed him to act, a spur on his legs"
>
> "The realisation spread through his body turning the keys of his body sending him into a frenzy of motion"

**2. If the realisation causes him to have an emotional change,** you could describe this as:

> "The realisation created a pause, a hidden tension rushing out of his body, water down the tap
>
> "A scream of anguish ripped the air, as a poison, slowly eating away at his heart, released."

**3. If the realisation causes him to know something, e.g. a scientific secret,** the metaphor could be:

> "The realisation hit him, he became Archimedes in his bathtub, for a second."
>
> "The idea spread through his body, over his tongue, and he tasted it, a soft, caramel flavour"

Answer (score 0):

This one is not much different, but I might write, "[Some thing or event] ignited in him a burning desire."